# Read part of a file as text and part as binary

Tags: c#

I have a file done like this

`10 NDI 27  2477    6358    4197    -67 0   VVFAˆ ÿÿÿÿ`

The last column is binary.
I have to read this file, the problem is that I can not read it as a text because in some lines the last columns has a new line character and thus I wouldn't read the entire line.
Then I should read it as a binary file, but then how can I retrieve the first and the third column?
I tried by reading bytes in this way:

```
byte[] lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\dynamic\\ap1_dynamic\\AP_1.txt");
```

And then convert it into string with

```
 for (i = 0; i < lines1.Length; i++) {
       Convert.ToString(lines1[i],2);
 }
```

but then it reads everything as 0 and 1.. I would like to read the first 8 columns as text, while the last one as binary..

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C#.

Comment: What if your binary data contains a line feed? Can your file contain multiple lines of such data?

Comment: This will only be practical if the text is fixed length (which it looks like it might be). Is it?

Comment: Yes it is. The binary data contains a line feed for sure because it goes to new line..

Comment: is the size of the binary data encoded in the textual part? or how else would you know when the end of the binary data is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file as binary is correct, as you can convert part of the binary data to text. In this context binary means bytes.

Converting the bytes to binary is not what you want to do. In this context binary means text representation in base 2, but you don't want a text representation of the data.

If the lines are fixed length, you can do something like this to read the values:

```
int lineLen = 70; // correct this with the actual length
int firstPos = 0;
int firstLen = 3; // correct with actual length
int thirdPos = 15; // correct with actual position
int thirdLen = 3; // correct with actual length
int lastPos = 60; // correct with actual position
int lastLen = 10; // correct with actual length

int lines = lines.length / lineLength;
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
  int first = Int32.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(i * lineLen + firstPos, firstLen).Trim());
  int third = Int32.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(i * lineLen + thirdPos, thirdLen).Trim());
  byte[] last = new byte[lastLen];
  Array.Copy(lines1, i * lineLen + lastPos, last, 0, lastLen);
  // do something with the data in first, third and last
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks this might help me! But.. the length of the line is not always the same, I mean the structure is like this, but in the first place I can also have a number like 11560 and thus the length will change each time..

Comment: @ayasha: Then you have a problem... From what you have told there is no certain way to determine where each line begins. If the binary data happens to contains something that looks like the beginning of a line, then you will have a hard time to write code that can determine that. Theoretically the binary data could contain something that looks like a complete other line, so it is impossible to tell if it is an actual line or part of the binary data. You simply need some more information that you can use to determine how long each line is.